# VB6 variable recordset name

Tags: ms-access, vb6

Is it possibile to access a recordset using a variable for the name ?

For example, i've a table with 10 fields called Name01,Name02,Name03.....Name10. I need to cycle through them so it would be nice to just use one instruction insted of repeating the same one with 10 different name.

This is the code i'm using now

```
Sal01 = rsUtility!Order01

Sal02 = rsUtility!Order02

.... 

Sal10 = rsUtility!Order10
```

This is what i would like to accomplish :

```
for i = 1 to 10 
    VariableName = "Order" & i 
    Sal(i) = rsUtility!VariableName 
next i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your variables have a 2 digit ending, you gotta use a proper format and not just `"Order" & i`, because it will result in `Order1` and not `Order01`

```
For i = 1 to 10 
    Sal(i) = rsUtility("Order" & Format(i,"00") )
Next i
```

The loop above will assign a value to a corresponding array element from DB variables in the range from `Order01` to `Order10` inclusive

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:

```vb
for i = 1 to 10 
    VariableName = "Order" & i 
    Sal(i) = rsUtility(VariableName)
next i
```